# Use ! as header in an R data frame

Tags: r

I am generating an input file to a model, which requires the first column to have header ! and value *. How do I do this in R data frame, please? Is it even possible? I know in Python this is allowed. Thank you! FYI, the results should look like this. A naive code is like below, but it doesn't work.

```
data_frame$! = "*"
```

[image]

Comment: Try `dat <- data.frame("!" = rep("*", 10), check.names = FALSE)`. And if you want to assign a value to this column you have to use backticks `dat$\`!\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely create such a data frame:

```
a = data.frame('!' = rep('*', 10), check.names = FALSE)

a$`!`
# [1] "*" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*"
```